# How to add a sub directory to WordPress single posts without affecting other post types?

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, directory, pods-framework

I've been trying to add a subdirectory to my blog post's permalink for example domain.com/blog/post-slug/

However, this is affecting the other post types that I've created using Pods such as domain.com/knowledgebase/ is now domain.com/blog/knowledgebase/

I would appreciate anyone helping me solve this problem. I still just want a blog as a subdirectory for my posts but I need the other post types not affected by that change.

Comment: What method did you use to add the `/blog/` prefix? There might be a super easy fix for this but it all assumes you used one specific method of doing it

Comment: I didn't spot that you mentioned you were using Pods, I left an answer below but that's for generic WP, by using Pods you've restricted yourself to those familiar with Pods, so I don't know if the equivalent option is available via the Pods framework. As an aside, you can generate CPT's by just filling out a form on a generator site, you don't need a plugin to create them for you

Answer (score 1):

If we look at the `register_post_type` documentation, in the rewrite option, there is a sub-option that controls this:

> `'with_front'` => `bool` Should the permalink structure be prepended with the front base. (example: if your permalink structure is /blog/, then your links will be: false->/news/, true->/blog/news/). Defaults to true

So something like this:

```php
    ...
    'rewrite' => [ 'with_front' => false ],
    ...
```

[More information on `register_post_type` rewrite options](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/#rewrite)

Comment: I haven't used 'Pods', but is the OP going to be able to make that adjustment using Pods?

Comment: Oh dear, I didn't spot that they were using Pods

Comment: May still be able to, could be a configurable option when making a CPT, I genuinely don't know.  I don't think CPT UI has it as an option and I don't recall ever seeing it in ToolSet Types either, but I avoid using them so I may be misremembering.

Comment: Same here, fingers crossed Pods maps an option on to this